# Kronecker product of 3 matrices using Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, kronecker-product

Suppose that we have 2 2X2 numpy arrays:

```
X=np.array([[0,1],[1,0]])
```

and

```
I=np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
```

Consider the Kronecker product

```
XX=X^X
```

where I have let the symbol `^` be the symbol for Kronecker product. This can easily be computed via the `numpy.kron()` function in python:

```
import numpy as np
kronecker_product = np.kron(X, X)
```

Now, suppose that we want to compute

```
XX=I^X^X
```

`numpy.kron()` only takes two arrays as arguments and expects them to be the same dimension. How can I perform this operation using `numpy.kron()` or other technique in python?

Comment: What about `np.kron(I, np.kron(X, X))`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As with anything like this, try:

```
XX = np.kron(I, np.kron(X, X))
```

Output:

```
>>> XX
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

You can nest calls to `kron` any number of times. For example, for `XX = A^B^C^D^E`, use

```
XX = np.kron(A, np.kron(B, np.kron(C, np.kron(D, E))))
```

If you don't like the verbosity there, you could create an alias for `np.kron`:

```
k = np.kron
XX = k(A, k(B, k(C, k(D, E))))
```

Or, better yet, use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) from the Python built-in module [`functools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) to do it in an even more readable fashion:

```
import functools as ft

lst = [A, B, C, D, E]
XX = ft.reduce(np.kron, lst)
```

Note: I tested all of this and it works perfectly.